# Time complexity of algorithm with g(n) complexity of O(n^2)

Tags: time, complexity-theory, mergesort

I have just learnt about the time complexity of various sorting method. (e.g Merge Sort, quick sort) However i am still a beginner at this field.
I know that if g(n) has a complexity of O(n) the whole time complexity of this method would be n logn. But what if the complexity of `g(n) is O(n^2)?`

```
void f(n) { 
    if (n <= 1) return;
    else { 
      g(n); 
      f(n/2);
      f(n/2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity recurrence relation is

[image]

– where `G(n)` is the time complexity of `g(n)`. Methods to solve this for e.g. `O(n^2)`:

1. Expansion (dropping the `O(...)` until the end):

   [image]

   – after `m` expansions. The second term contains a *geometric series* which [converges to 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_%E2%8B%AF), so it can be ignored as a constant. Applying the stopping condition `n = 1`:

   [image]
2. The [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)). For the example:

   [image]

   – which means Case 3 applies. Therefore the result is consistent with (1):

   [image]

Comment: Is the general formulae valid for all type of recursion ? Are there other formulas that can help me find the time complexity of other methods. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @JiaZhengLua the Master theorem formula only works for recurrences with **one** recursive term where the argument is **divided** by a factor, e.g. i) `T(n/2)`, but not e.g. ii) `T(n/2) + T(n/3)` or iii) `T(n-1)`. For a situation such as ii) one can use the [Akra-Bazzi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method).